How to Silence Deprecation Warning in Gulp Sass Task - "The legacy JS API is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0."
My current installation is the follow:

Node - v20.18.0 Gulp - v5.0.0 Gulp-Sass - v5.1.0 Sass - v1.80.6

My gulpfile.js:
const gulp = require("gulp");
const sass = require("gulp-sass")(require("sass"));
 
gulp.task("sass", function(){
  return gulp
    .src("./src/sass/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"));
});

Running "gulp sass" completes the task successfully, however it issues two deprecation warnings, one for each scss file processed:
❯ gulp sass
[13:05:58] Using gulpfile ~\Dev\Udemy\Gulp4\Section2\gulpfile.js
[13:05:58] Starting 'sass'...
Deprecation Warning: The legacy JS API is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
 
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/legacy-js-api
 
Deprecation Warning: The legacy JS API is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
 
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/legacy-js-api
 
[13:05:58] Finished 'sass' after 87 ms

I thoroughly read the documentation of both gulp-sass and sass, however I'm unable to silence these deprecation warnings by setting "silenceDeprecations" to the correct value in the gulpfile.js. It's a pain to have to scroll through these warnings when process multiple scss files.
Does anyone have a working solution?

I presuming that as deprecation comes closed hiding them would be disabled, as very soon it will not work at all anymore? The best way to get rid of deprecation warnings is to... update.

You can add an option silenceDeprecations to temporarily hide these warnings:
const gulp = require("gulp");
const sass = require("gulp-sass")(require("sass"));
 
gulp.task("sass", function(){
  return gulp
    .src("./src/sass/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass({
      silenceDeprecations: ['legacy-js-api'],
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"));
});


The OP mentions that setting this did not help?

Works, thanks!
This stuff is so annoying... Why did they had to change it with @use and @forward. Bunch of redundant writing for a simple scss compiling task
